# Venezuela JVectorMap doesn't work

Tags: jquery, .net, html, jvectormap

I'm trying to show the map of Venezuela with JVectorMap, just the easy sample with the next code:

$('#map').vectorMap({map: 've_en'});

But, it doesn't work. I have the .js "ve_en" which I downloaded from http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/venezuela/

This is my div:

I have this same code in other page with the map of the USA and it does work. Please, may anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have all files downloaded from the new site. It definitely works because you can see rendered map on the [jvectormap.com](http://jvectormap.com).

Comment: I'm using exactly this code: $('#map').vectorMap({ 
                                   map: 'usa_en',
                                   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                   color: '#8d8d8d'
                               }); and it works. But I try to update 'usa_en' to 've_en' and it doesn't work. I try to update it to other map like 'germany_en' and 'europe_en' and they do work! So, my question is: is there something different with Venezuela map?? Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing the background color of the map and it's being shown in "white". The complete code should be:

```
$('#map').vectorMap({map: 've_mill_en', backgroundColor: 'black' });
```

Take a look at an example of Venezuela's Map drawn in a black background:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmking/ADEXq

and here's the result:

[image]

Comment: There's a state missing. i.e. an state is shown in black and appears to be part of the lake locate to the west of it.